# Make Grub2 boot into Windows/old kernel once

Tags: debian, grub2

How can I make Grub2 boot into windows or an old kernel once (i.e Windows becomes the default option for once and grub boots into that after the timeout)? The reason being:

1. My keyboard usually hangs during Grub timeout screen
2. I would like to make the command (after the configuration, if possible) an alias (e.g `bootonce`). So whenever I want to boot into Windows or an old kernel I would just run the alias and Grub would boot into that option without me having to choose it manually from the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `/etc/default/grub` set

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
```

then run `update-grub`.

After that you can use `grub-reboot number` (with `number` being the entry number of your Windows in the grub menu list).

More details can be found on the [debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/GrubReboot)

Comment: @sterz You have to watch out that depending on the grub setup that number might change when a new kernel is installed. I used to have that problem, but now my grub hides "old" kernels in a sub-menu and the position of windows does not change anymore.

Comment: Same here. My grub also hides 'em.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `startupmanager` for this issue.

Just run:

```
sudo apt-get install startupmanager
```

You can easily choose which OS you want to boot with this application, and you can change timeouts with it too.